# How to configure Azure Web App Bot as an App in Teams

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have been working on QnAMaker based web app bot in Azure, the developed bot works fine in web chat
I am now looking for creating Bot as a MS TEAMs app and use there, for this purpose.
First I have added TEAMS as a channel in the Web App Bot and looking into how I can create the bot as an App using Teams App Studio - Manifest Editor.

My Questions are

1. Is it a correct way to use App Studio Manifest editor to create an app if we want Bot App to be used as Line of business app in organization's Tenant? Is there any clear documentation on this?
2. Can we also use Power Virtual Agents for the same purpose?

Answer (score 1):

So it's definitely possible to do what you're doing and I think it's a good way to start, especially if you are new to Bot development - getting the bot up and running by itself, and then integrating it into Teams. You can definitely bring it into Teams at this point using App Studio's "Bot" section, and then deploy using App Studio as well to your test account. When you want to deploy it to the rest of the tenant, you can download the app manifest from App Studio and upload it to the Tenant's app store for wider use.

It's important to note though that are a whole bunch of ways to create bot apps, so the documentation might well lean towards one or another. For instance, the Teams Toolkit will start with a different way to register things and a different type of language and bot starting point. That doesn't mean one approach is more valid or even more preferred. There's a main "starting point" for docs though that will be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots

Power Virtual Agents is *another* possible route, and for Teams specifically you can see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/add-power-virtual-agents-bot-to-teams). It's a very different hosting model, development model, and possibly pricing model for PVA though.

If you're new to bots entirely, there are a bunch of other topics worth reading up on, like LUIS, Language Generation, Dialogs, and more. For your context though, I'd suggest looking more in LUIS in particular to deal with things beyond the basic Q+A capabilities (e.g. what to do when the bot can't find an answer in the KB).

Comment: If OP already has a bot, then absolutely the right route is creating App Manifest through Teams App Studio, sideloading for testing, then uploading to the Tenant's app store once ready. Just a note that Power Virtual Agents is much more expensive. Typically a QnA bot might run up $300/month if it has its own App Service Plan and Azure Search resource. PVA runs $1,000/month for 2,000 sessions plus $450 incremental for additional blocks of 1,000 sessions.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I'm struggling to make sense of the pricing on PVA, and not sure if there's some allowance included with an M365 license. Wondering if you know?

Comment: There is no allowance for PVA, we have deemed it too costly for our organization since we already are building bots in Bot Framework proper, though some of the additional features with PVA are quite nice.

Comment: Thanks Hilton & @billoverton for productive conversation, i think i should go for App Studio Manifest editor to create and distribute app.

Comment: Sounds good - give it a go keep us posted